# Cursor does not show/blink in dark cell in Spreadsheetgear

Tags: .net, wpf, spreadsheetgear

I am using `SpreadsheetGear` in our `WPF` project.

**The cursor color is black:**
In the light color cell, blinking of the cursor is visible But in the dark color cell cursor is not visible clearly.

Please see this GIF

[image: Cursor does not show/blink in dark cell in Spreadsheetgear]

How can make it visible? Any Idea?
Is it possible to change cursor color or is it possible to use doted (with black-white) line bar

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change the caret color used for the in-cell editor on the WorkbookView.  One workaround would be if you also have a FormulaBar control associated with the WorkbookView, as its content won’t take on the formatting of the cell being edited (e.g., black text on white background) and so make the caret position more easily located.